# apply a function in r

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I have to generate data via sampling process and apply a function.

```
    p = 10; f = 8
   set.seed (123)
    pars <- data.frame (id = 1:p, 
     value = sample (c("AA", "AB", "AB", "BB"),p, replace = TRUE))
    pars
     id value
1   1    AB
2   2    BB
3   3    AB
4   4    BB
5   5    BB
6   6    AA
7   7    AB
8   8    BB
9   9    AB
10 10    AB


fdat <- data.frame (t(combn(pars$id,2)))
set.seed (1234)
sdf <- fdat[sample(1:nrow(fdat), f),]
names (sdf) <- c("P1", "P2")
sdf
   P1 P2
6   1  7
28  4  8
27  4  7
43  8  9
36  6  7
26  4  6
1   1  2
9   1 10
```

Value for each combination to be applied is in the table pars. For example for first P1 and P2 combination 1 = "AB", 7 = "AB". For second, 4 = "BB", 8 = "BB".

Now I want to apply the following function to sdf (considering the value in pars table). P2.v is value of P1, P2.v is value of P2.

```
genofun <- function (P1.v, P2.v, n) {
if (P1.v == "AA" & P2.v == "BB" ) {
    CLD <- rep ("AB", n)
    } 
if (P1.v == "BB" & P2.v == "AA" ) {
    CLD <- rep ("AB", n)
    }
if (P1.v == "AA" & P2.v == "AB") {
   CLD <- sample (c("AA", "AB"), n, replace = TRUE)
   }
 if (P1.v == "AB" & P2.v == "AA") {
   CLD <- sample (c("AA", "AB"), n, replace = TRUE)
   }
if (P1.v == "BB" & P2.v == "AB") {
   CLD <- sample (c("BB", "AB"), n, replace = TRUE)
   }
if ( P1.v == "AB" & P2.v == "BB") {
   CLD <- sample (c("BB", "AB"), n, replace = TRUE)
   }   
if (P1.v == "BB" & P2.v == "BB") {
   CLD <- rep("BB", n, replace = TRUE)
   }
if (P1.v == "AA" & P2.v == "AA") {
   CLD <- rep("AA", n)
   }
if (P1.v == "AB" & P2.v == "AB") {
   CLD <- sample(c("AA", "AB","AB", "BB"), n, replace = TRUE)
   }
 out <- c(P1.v, P2.v, CLD)
return (out)
}
n = 5
genofun (P1, P2, n)
```

Thus expected output would be :

```
    P1 P2  P1.v  P2.v  CLD1  CLD2   CLD3   CLD4  CLD5 <- (essentially number columns = n)
6   1  7
28  4  8
27  4  7
43  8  9
36  6  7
26  4  6
1   1  2
9   1 10
```

Comment: thanks ttmaccer for pointing out and jon for correcting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there appears to be an error in the definition of `genofun` but once that is fixed the following should work:

```
P1v<-as.character(pars$value[sdf$P1])
P2v<-as.character(pars$value[sdf$P2])
dum<-cbind(sdf,t(mapply(genofun,P1.v=P1v,P2.v=P2v,n=5)))
names(dum)<-c('P1','P2','P1.v','P2.v','CLD1','CLD2','CLD3','CLD4','CLD5')
 > dum
   P1 P2 P1.v P2.v CLD1 CLD2 CLD3 CLD4 CLD5
6   1  7   AB   AB   AA   AB   AB   AB   AA
28  4  8   BB   BB   BB   BB   BB   BB   BB
27  4  7   BB   AB   AB   BB   AB   BB   AB
43  8  9   BB   AB   AB   BB   BB   BB   AB
36  6  7   AA   AB   AB   AA   AA   AB   AA
26  4  6   BB   AA   AB   AB   AB   AB   AB
1   1  2   AB   BB   AB   AB   AB   AB   AB
9   1 10   AB   AB   AB   BB   AA   AB   AB
>
```